# What is Wonder Woman's magic lasso woven from?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman

Incredibly strong, able to stretch and contract, and a magical lie detector created by the Gods of old... What is DC Comics Wonder Woman's lasso of truth made of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wonder Woman's **Magic Lasso of Aphrodite** or **Lasso of Truth** has two origins.

[Post-Crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earths) origin (more familiar to most fans):

> was forged by the god Hephaestus from the Golden Girdle of Gaea that was once worn by Antiope, sister of Hippolyta.

This information comes from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_of_Truth)

[image]

[Pre-Crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Infinite_Earth), according to the [DC Wiki](http://dc.wikia.com/), is much the same (if much less specific):

> lasso was formed from Aphrodite's girdle.

As you can see when **George Pérez** re-booted the Amazonian's origin he went for [Gaea](http://www.theoi.com/Protogenos/Gaia.html), goddess of the earth, rather than Aphrodite. As [Pérez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_P%C3%A9rez#Wonder_Woman) had a very [different view point](http://goodcomics.comicbookresources.com/2013/06/26/committed-perez-wonder-woman-the-gold-standard/) on Princess Diana of Themyscira in the 1980's when he worked on her book than [**William Marston**](http://www.comicbookresources.com/?page=article&id=7921) did when [he created her](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Moulton_Marston#Wonder_Woman) in the 1940's.